# array() to var addresses =['location1','location2'] conversion in javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have using jsp form and javascript for google map location.The jsp form have a property in location. Get locations and stored to locationNameArr.

```
var form=document.getElementById("searchForm");
var locationNameArr=new Array();
locationNameArr=form.location;
```

The locations have directly given and its working fine in google map.

```
 var addresses =['location1','location1'];
```

How to assign the my location to variable addresses.

```
var addresses = locationNameArr ?
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: How to assign the my location(locationNameArr) to variable addresses?

Answer (score 0):

> How to assign the my location(locationNameArr) to variable addresses?

It is as simple as:

```
var addresses = location.city1;
```

I suppose that the `location` is something like this:

```
location = { city1: ['location1', 'location2'], 
             city2: ['location3', 'location4']
           };
```

If so, in the `addresses` above we assign the following array:

```
['location3', 'location4']
```

What we have done above is to create an object literal with keys the cities and values array's with the corresponding locations. So when we want to get the locations of the `city1`, we simply use the dot notation, `location.city1`.